# Q: dual-boot : Windows 10 and Kubuntu 16.10 -> GRUB corrupt every Windows boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I going out of my mind....

I cannot boot in normal way on my Kubuntu 16.10. I've got installed it on my /dev/sda3 as below. I started to have some issues with my installation (after installing EXT2FS on my Win 10) and decided to install Kubuntu once again.

Normal procedure. Format /dev/sda3 on EXT4, make SWAP, install boot on /dev/sda and so on.

All is good.

Kubuntu is starting normal.

Till I will go into Windows 10. When it will boot up, it is making some changes, and therefore when I want to boot it, this happens :

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

One time solution - go info LiveCD, use BOOT-REPAIR and it will work. Till I will start Windows 10 once again.

I've got this situation on /dev/sda

```
(parted) print all
Model: ATA SanDisk SD8SN8U- (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      525MB   176GB  175GB   primary   ntfs
 3      176GB   254GB  78,5GB  primary   ext4
 4      254GB   256GB  1998MB  extended
 5      254GB   256GB  1998MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

 paczek@paczek-HP850:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  9,8M  777M   2% /run
/dev/sda3        72G  5,2G   63G   8% /
tmpfs           3,9G   88K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/119
tmpfs           787M   12K  787M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2       163G  116G   48G  71% /media/paczek/58BC825ABC823294
```

LOG from BOOT-REPAIR :

http://pastebin.com/Tbq0W6Td

Secure Boot is off, and I am using Legacy Boot. Installation has been made also in Legacy Mode.

Any clue ?

Edit[ 1]:
I've changed topic to be more precisely.

Edit[2]: Fast startup option is **DISABLED**

[Windows-Power Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n42Yf.png)

I would like to add, that on first installation of Kubuntu (ealier) everything was ok. It was also 16.10 version like now.

Edit[3]:
Like oldfred suggested I've tied to exit from BusyBox, which gave me this error :

```
A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) exit 
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
/init: line 338: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
[54.698904] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!! exitcode=0x00000200
[54.698931] CP: 2 PID: 1 Comm: init Nowt tainted 4.8.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu
// There is some complicated Call Trace
[54.699241] ---[ end KErnel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
```

Edit [4] : 
Ok, according to this answer (sorry, I cannot use more than 2 links) : askubuntu.com/questions/25695/initramfs-error-during-boot

I've repaired my ubuntu partition and Kubuntu boot without problem !!

Here is summary of `fsck` 
pastebin.com/fHKTdUt7

But when I will try to boot Win once again, I think everything will get back to problem.

Edit[5]: 
Yes, booting into Windows made the same issue once again. 
Someone, please, help.

Comment: Are you leaving Windows fast start up  (hibernation on?) http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: No, this option is disabled, added information above

Comment: If you type `exit` at busybox does it boot?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't. It goes into `kernel panic` .I've added some more info above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to resolve my problem.

From what I've understood - main problem has happened after installing EXT2FSD v0.69 on Windows 10.

First thing I've been done was uninstalling it before any further work. But  yesterday - I've found that even after uninstalling, service of EXT2FSD was installed and working on my system.

I've deleted it by

```
sc delete ext2fsd
```

then fixed ext4 filesystem by `fsck` and all problems gone....

Comment: Microsoft agrees with you: Microsoft says don't do it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/